# How to update all fields dynamically in Instead of UPDATE trigger SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am implementing Instead of UPDATE trigger in SQL-server, want to update all the fields without being in need to cache the values from the INSERTED table and then set it to the fields in the UPDATE Query .. How Can I do This ?!

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Instead_updTable1 ON dbo.Table1
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF (UPDATE(ID))
           RAISERROR ('It is not allowed to update a Table1.ID', 16, 1)
    ELSE
           BEGIN
                UPDATE dbo.Table1
                SET * = (SELECT * FROM INSERTED JOIN DELETED ON INSERTED.ID = DELETED.ID)
           END
END
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing to do here? `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` triggers are usually only used when you want to completely bypass normal update logic and do something completely custom. It appears you actually want normal update logic here.

Comment: Sidenote: `raiserror` with severity 16 does not prevent updates from being made. You need to add `rollback transaction` if you want the update to actually be cancelled.

Comment: @mroach I want to deny updating of ID and accept any other update .. I know that these code doesn't show that , I was only trying to get access the normal update values and then will write my code .. 
Sorry if it was fuzzy somehow

Comment: this seems like a bad idea.   Transactions should have good visibility to the developer.   The transaction can be accomplished by a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to be using an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger. These are only needed when you want to completely bypass all normal table update logic and do something completely custom. Usually this is done when putting a trigger on a complex view.

You said you want to deny updating a value. No problem. You can just do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Table1_UPDATE on Table1 FOR UPDATE AS
  IF UPDATE(ID)
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('You may not update the ID', 16, -1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RETURN
  END
GO
```

1. `RAISERROR` will of course raise the error, alerting the user that they've done something bad. One might assume that this would halt execution and rollback the update, but it does neither (unless `XACT_ABORT` is `ON`).
2. `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` will undo the entire update, restoring the table to the state it was in before the `UPDATE` was attempted.
3. `RETURN` exits the trigger code. There's likely no need to continue further processing.

If you do want to update the base table, here's how you do it:

```
UPDATE t1 SET
       field1 = i.field1,
       field2 = i.field2,
       -- all additional fields go here
FROM   Table1 t1
       INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.id = t1.id
```

`inserted` is a virtual table containing the entire row complete with new values. `deleted` has the rows as they were before the insert. So they can be used to see which values changed.

Sidenote: If a field is an `IDENTITY` column, you can't update it anyway, which obviates the need for such a trigger.

Comment: `UPDATE()` doesn't check if the value have changed. better compare the value between inserted and deleted tables.